how to find new tokens by analyzing transactions on the solana network?
How could I identify the creation of a new token on the Solana network? Any standard log_messages for this?
I'm learning to work on the Solana network.
I tried fetching new token creation using Program log: InitializeMint
but this returns old tokens too.
I'm using solana for python

Look for the log
Program log: Create

and parse the instructionslist find the instruction where
programId: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
and where Account program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL is also in the Account list.
You can also assert these messages in the logs to exist:
InitializeAccount3
MintTo
Create Metadata

Example transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/5mV4tH6jvyaNAYqsCHmwjeDpKCZ4AnNKi4v7ecDK5iJF4PHb9GfRYWTj9DyXHZyuuE16GAK4rcJryNRBGo8aFY16
Parse it, study the instructions and assert the logMessages and you will see the match!
